# How to display 1 record from an XML file using ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm pretty sure I have the syntax all wrong. This is for a detail view of a foreach statement. In the index view, I'm displaying every record. I just want a detail view that will display a record when you click detail on it. I've tried changing the model class to iEnum, iList, and some other stuff. Is there a way to get the view to print out a single record from an XML file? Project below. Thank you.

View: (Detail)

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Details";
}

<h2>Details</h2>

<div>
    <h4>Personal</h4>
    <hr />
    @foreach (PersonsApplicationFromXMLFile.Models.Personal persons in Model)
    {
    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
        <dt>
            Name
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @persons.Name
        </dd>

        <dt>
            Gender
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @persons.Gender
        </dd>

        <dt>
            City
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @persons.City
        </dd>

    </dl>
    }
</div>
<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</p>
```

View: (Index)

```
    @{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<style>
    table tr td {
        padding: 0 20px;
        border:5px solid black;
    }
</style>
@Html.ActionLink("Create new Record", "Create")
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>@Html.ActionLink("ID", "Index", new { sortOrder = "ID" })</th>
        <th>@Html.ActionLink("Name", "Index", new { sortOrder = "Name" })</th>
        <th>Gender</th>
        <th>@Html.ActionLink("City", "Index", new { sortOrder = "City" })</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (PersonsApplicationFromXMLFile.Models.Personal personal in Model)
    {
    <tr>
        <td>@personal.ID</td>
        <td>@personal.Name</td>
        <td>@personal.Gender</td>
        <td>@personal.City</td>
        <td>@Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details") |</td>

    </tr>
    }
</table>``
```

Controller: (Detail)

```
    // GET: Person/Details/5
    public ActionResult Details(string ID)
    {
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(Some file...);
        IEnumerable<Personal> persons = doc.SelectNodes("/Persons/record")
            .Cast<XmlNode>()
            .Select(node => new Personal()
            {
                ID = node["ID"].InnerText,
                Name = node["Name"].InnerText,
                Email = node["Email"].InnerText,
                DateOfBirth = node["DateOfBirth"].InnerText,
                Gender = node["Gender"].InnerText,
                City = node["City"].InnerText
            });
        return View(persons.ToList());
    }
```

Comment: You just want it to display the first record? The view is going to render everything in Model.

Comment: you want the view to render just one specific person in the list?

Comment: I've edited the question to make it a little more understandable?

Comment: @user780613 Yes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I Guess you want to print the data with specified id in the details.
here is the fix.

```
public ActionResult Details(string ID)
    {
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(Some file...);
        Personal person = doc.SelectNodes("/Persons/record")
            .Cast<XmlNode>()
            .Where(node=>ID.Equals(node["ID"].InnerText)
            .Select(node => new Personal()
            {
                ID = node["ID"].InnerText,
                Name = node["Name"].InnerText,
                Email = node["Email"].InnerText,
                DateOfBirth = node["DateOfBirth"].InnerText,
                Gender = node["Gender"].InnerText,
                City = node["City"].InnerText
            }).FirstOrDefault();
        return View(person);
    }
```

And in the View

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Details";
}

<h2>Details</h2>

<div>
    <h4>Personal</h4>
    <hr />


    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
        <dt>
            Name
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Model.Name
        </dd>

        <dt>
            Gender
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Model.Gender
        </dd>

        <dt>
            City
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Model.City
        </dd>

    </dl>        
</div>
<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</p>
```

Comment: The important thing is to return a single item rather than a list of selections